# Impossible to run php-fpm on server restarts (Ubuntu 12.04 x64)

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, update

I'm setting up a server with nginx + php-fpm (5.4.11) on ubuntu 12.04 LTS (x64)

I installed nginx from the repository and I compiled PHP myself. Everythings work fine when I start php-fpm and nginx

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php-5.4.11-fpm start
sudo service nginx start
```

I can display a phpinfo on a webpage, so far so good.

pid is set like this in /etc/php-5.4.11/php-fpm.conf

```
pid = /var/run/php-5.4.11/php-fpm.pid
```

and from /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-5.4.11/php-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Now, I would like to start PHP when the server reboots, so I did:

```
update-rc.d php-5.4.11-fpm defaults
```

But when I restart the server, I got this error in the log file:

```
ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/var/run/php-5.4.11/php-fpm.sock': No such file or directory (2)
```

And indeed, the directory that I created myself /var/run/php-5.4.11/ has disappeared. If I create it again and do sudo /etc/init.d/php-5.4.11-fpm start, it works. But If I restart the server, the directory will be deleted and php-fpm won't start.

What's wrong, I don't get it?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, tmpfs is mounted to the /var/run. In other words, this is a RAM-disk and it's clean at OS start.

In this case you should point "pid" and "listen" directives of your php-fpm pool configuration  straight to the /var/run:

```
pid = /var/run/php-fpm.pid

[www]
listen = /var/run/php-fpm.sock
```

Comment: I wonder if this work if you have multiple vhosts? What happens when they share the same path to sock and pid?

Comment: You're a legend - this saved me so much time.  In my pool.d/ config, I added a [global] override for pid=/var/run/php7.0-fpm.pid and then PHP would restart.  Thanks!